# Getting Lat and Long in SalesForce

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm new to SalesForce and I'm working on an app that requires me to calculate distance between two given addresses.

User enters 2 addresses and then I calculate the distance between those two addresses. I can use Google Map API and get this done, but I don't know how to use it.

Can someone help me on this? I've looked through a lot of threads and they are too old or too complex.

Or, can some one at least guide me to something that might help?

If I have the longitude and latitude of the location, then I can find distance using "Geolocation" function. But, how do I get the longitude and latitude?

Comment: You'll likely need an external API for that, such as [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Once you picked one, you need to use API calls to [geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) the addresses.

Comment: If those external APIs are acceptable to you, I can add an answer with some example code on calling them, and updating fields.

Comment: Please, can you add an example code? that will be a big help

Comment: This question should really just be posted on [so], but it sounds like @battery.cord is helping you out, so I won't flag to close...yet.

Comment: I'm working on a Salesforce specific example (Ex, using Custom Settings to store API keys). If the question was just how to use Google's API, I'd agree with the migration.

Comment: I want to stay within salesforce. I'd like to avoid Google Map, if I could. I need SalesForce specific example

Comment: No, that's the point. You need to make a callout. No matter what you do.

Comment: Geolocation on-platform was made available in Summer '16 for the standard address fields using data.com clean rules. Details [here in the Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_general_geocodes_aloha.htm).

Comment: Wha?! Mind = blown. You should add an answer to that effect. @MarkPond

Comment: ^ If your addresses fall onto those Standard fields. And that should be an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As of Summer '16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_general_geocodes_aloha.htm), you can take advantage of platform supported geolocation for certain standard fields.

These fields are:

> 1. `BillingAddress` on Accounts
> 2. `ShippingAddress` on Accounts
> 3. `MailingAddress` on Contacts
> 4. `Address` on Leads

You can read more on [Set up Geocode Clean Rules](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/data_dot_com_clean_add_geocode_information_to_all_records.htm).

---

An example from the provided documentation:

> You add an account with a value of `One Market Street, San Francisco, CA 94105-5188, United States` for the `Billing Address` field. When you save this account, values for the `BillingLatitude`, `BillingLongitude`, and `BillingGeocodeAccuracy` fields are added.
>
> - `37.793819` to `BillingLatitude`
> - `-122.395089` to `BillingLongitude`
> - `Address` to `BillingGeocodeAccuracy`

---

> Available in: Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

---

Credit to this answer goes to @MarkPond for mentioning it in the comments.

Comment: already got it with clean rules. working just fine. thanks guys!

Comment: The URL you posted is not working anymore, looks like they started deprecating this topic, did anyone managed to make those rules work lately?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a function I used in an older project which does exactly this, using some custom settings to store the API Keys used for the transactions. This example does require you to have a valid Google Maps API Key, which you can get from [their site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key). Be aware that you do run the risk of going over the provided limits with a free account, and if you need to have a large number of users providing information, you may have to upgrade. You can read more about the limits (Which I would add to this post, but they are subject to change) [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).

Once you obtain your keys, I highly recommend placing them in a [Custom Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm), and using that in your code to manage any future changes, as well as to prevent it from being hard coded in a number of files, if you ever need it in multiple locations. You can also use the setting to store additional configuration information (In my case, I was using it to store callback information to generate a json file).

[image: Google_API_Key__c]

This code uses the [`Http`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) and [`HttpRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) classes, and constrcuts a request url based on Google Documentation. It uses the `Google_API_Key__c` custom setting field, which pulls in the valid key, and adds it to the request. This code specifies a json request from the geocoding api, but this can be modified.

```
public class GoogleAPI_Handler {
    // Example url construction 
    // 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + key

    public static Map<String, Object> Request(String address) {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

            MEP_MapSettings__c d = MEP_MapSettings__c.getInstance('Default');

            // Can only request a single address at a time 
            String endpoint = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address;
            endpoint += '&key=' + d.Google_API_Key__c;

            request.setEndpoint(endpoint.replace(' ', '+')); // Remove spaces in addresses 
            request.setMethod('GET');

            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            Map<String, Object> resultJSON = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody()); 

            if ((String)resultJSON.get('status') != 'OK') {
                // Log/Handle error 
            } else {
                List<Object> apiResult = (List<Object>)resultJSON.get('results');

                Object actualResult = (Object)apiResult[0]; // Gets the 'address_components' section from the result

                Map<String, Object> returnMap = new Map<String, Object>();

                Map<String, Object> actualResultMap = (Map<String, Object>)actualResult; // Cast to Map to work with
                Map<String, Object> geo = (Map<String, Object>)actualResultMap.get('geometry'); // Move into geometry section- contains location data needed
                Map<String, Object> coords = (Map<String, Object>)geo.get('location'); // Contains exact location information

                returnMap.put('lng', coords.get('lng'));
                returnMap.put('lat', coords.get('lat'));

                returnMap.put('formatted_address', actualResultMap.get('formatted_address'));

                return returnMap;
            }

            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be editing a few sections in this snippet (notably the `Object actualResult = (Object)apiResult[0];` line) for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Google Maps Geocoding API` is what you need. Just go to [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com) to get an API key. They allow you 2500 requests a day for free.

**Apex Code Snippet**

```
@TestVisible
private static String buildAddress(Account account) {
    String address = '';

    if (account.BillingStreet != null) address += account.BillingStreet +', ';
    if (account.BillingCity != null) address += account.BillingCity +', ';
    if (account.BillingState != null) address += account.BillingState +' ';
    if (account.BillingPostalCode != null) address += account.BillingPostalCode +', ';
    if (account.BillingCountry != null) address += account.BillingCountry;

    address = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8');

    return address;
}

@TestVisible
private static HttpRequest buildWebServiceRequest(String address) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + key);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setTimeout(60000);

    return request;
}
@TestVisible
private static void handleResponse(HttpResponse response, Account account) {
    double lat;
    double lng;

    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());

    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'location') {
            parser.nextToken();

            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                String text = parser.getText();

                if (text.equals('lat')) {
                    parser.nextToken();
                    lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                }
                if (text.equals('lng')) {
                    parser.nextToken();
                    lng = parser.getDoubleValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    account.Main_Office_Geolocation__Latitude__s = lat;
    account.Main_Office_Geolocation__Longitude__s = lng;
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading another post from today this code needs to give some credit to the original author. I didn't find the snippets from there, but it seems that is where it most likely originated from. Possibly who originally [Authored](https://github.com/Internet-Creations) the code

Comment: Damn, the "authored" link did the job! Thanks a LOT!